# rack server won't start

Tags: server, ruby

I am a beginner to ruby and rack ; trying to start a rack server and the `rackup config.ru` command does nothing.

right now my rackup file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rack"
Rack::Server.start
```

And, the config.ru file is

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../testrequest"

$stderr = File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/log_output", "w")

class EnvMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # provides a way to test that lint is present
    if env["PATH_INFO"] == "/broken_lint"
      return [200, {}, ["Broken Lint"]]
    # provides a way to kill the process without knowing the pid
    elsif env["PATH_INFO"] == "/die"
      exit!
    end

    env["test.$DEBUG"]      = $DEBUG
    env["test.$EVAL"]       = BUKKIT if defined?(BUKKIT)
    env["test.$VERBOSE"]    = $VERBOSE
    env["test.$LOAD_PATH"]  = $LOAD_PATH
    env["test.stderr"]      = File.expand_path($stderr.path)
    env["test.Ping"]        = defined?(Ping)
    env["test.pid"]         = Process.pid
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

use EnvMiddleware
run Rack::Server.new
```

I have looked through a few online resources or questions here, but nothing would help. Thanks, if anyone can suggest the changes in these files or what to do.